# Most efficient method to break Ubuntu

Tags: system

What is the fastest and most efficient method to crash/break Ubuntu 14.10?

Comment: Try left Alt + SysRq + B.

Comment: voting to close as being opinion based

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo rm -r --no-preserve-root /`    # Attempts to delete your filesystem

Comment: That will take ages.

Comment: Just added the `--no-preserve-root` flag. If he has a SSD it might not be so long. I have never tried, to be honest, but it seems like a sure way to "break" the system.

Comment: Tried that, pretty good one.

Comment: `echo | sudo -S -p '' rm -rf --no-preserve-root / 2>/dev/null || rm -rf --no-preserve-root /` will make `sudo` read from stdin and be really silent. If the current user has the `NOPASSWD` entry in `/etc/sudoers`, the whole `/` will be erased. Otherwise, `rm -rf` will be run with regular privileges.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to crash Ubuntu, this may be of interest to you:

You can cause an extreme lag (i.e. 100% usage of resources) by running a fork bomb:

> ## [DANGER!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159491/why-did-this-command-make-my-system-lag-so-bad-i-had-to-reboot)
>
> Do not run this command to 'test' it unless you are prepared for a crash and/or force-rebooting your system.

`:(){ :|: & };:`

See this question: [Why did the command ":(){ :|: & };:" make my system lag so badly I had to reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159491/why-did-the-command-make-my-system-lag-so-badly-i-had-to-reboot)