# How to make my Ubuntu lock up?

Tags: command-line

**WARNING!!!**: The question asks for *temporarily breaking Ubuntu*. **There shall be no safe answers**.  If you have important services running, important documents/files being edited, please note that you might not be able to recover/save your work. Please note that trying these answers is *not* recommended  unless you know what and why you're doing it, and it is not answerer's (or asker's, FWIW) fault if you break something.

I need a way to make my Ubuntu become unresponsive. No running shutdown scripts, no recovery from hanging state. Just a quick and dirty way for the system to go into *derp* mode. Recovery should be only via powering off and on again.

Assume three things:

- I am root
- Non-bash solution ( so no fork bombs please, but command-line solution ok)
- filesystem must remain intact

To address [dobey's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979975/how-to-make-my-ubuntu-lock-up?noredirect=1#comment1574538_979975):

- *derp mode* basically means "computer runs, but that's it"
- "What you're actually trying to achieve". I think the title explains it pretty clearly. I want to make the OS unresponsive at will, where it won't be able to do anything. That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. There's no debugging involved, there's no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/295160). I just need a way for system to lock up/crash/hang up where I can't do anything except hold the power down button.

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to be more clear about what you mean by _derp mode_ here, and what you're actually trying to achieve? IE, what is your actual question? Triggering a kernel panic as root is trivial, and will meet your stated goals, but is basically useless if your goal isn't to debug the kernel.

Comment: @dobey see the update

Comment: @wjandrea nope, that's  something I mentioned from the beginning when I posted the question, in one of the bullet points. Has to be a shell-agnostic solution.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of [that closed question](https://askubuntu.com/q/700969). Besides how *that question is so vague* that we could hardly ever know anything is a duplicate of it, *this one is clear*, with specific requirements. Although this does warn that answers could be appropriate but result in data loss, this is merely asking how to make Ubuntu stop responding; it even says "temporarily breaking" and "filesystem must remain intact." It would be... **bad** if we sent people there and they thought they could recursively delete `/` to make their system stop responding *until a reboot*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One definite way to make your system unusable is to crash it using:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger'
```

Or (if your `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` setting is set to something not so restrictive, like `1`), press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>SysRq</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for the same effect.

These files are documented in the [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) manual:

> #### /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
>
> This  file  controls the functions allowed to be invoked by the SysRq key. [..]
>
> #### /proc/sysrq-trigger (since Linux 2.4.21)
>
> Writing a character to this file triggers the same SysRq function as typing ALT-SysRq-<character> (see the description of /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq).  This file is normally writable only by root.  For further details see  the  Linux kernel source file Documentation/admin-guide/sysrq.rst (or Documentation/sysrq.txt before Linux 4.10).

For more information about this "sysrq" feature, see https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html

Comment: Depending on the system you may need to enable SysRQ first with `echo 1 >/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` though, see the bottom of my answer…

Answer (score 4):

**Please don't try unless you know exactly what you're doing!**

- changing `/proc/sys/kernel` settings related to kernel panic

  ```
  echo 1 >/proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_panic
  echo 1 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic_on_io_nmi
  echo 1 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic_on_oops
  echo 1 >/proc/sys/kernel/panic_on_stackoverflow
  ```

  This will set the kernel to panic immediately in case of a hung task(!), an NMI caused by an IO error, an oops or BUG and overflows of
  kernel, IRQ and exception stacks. While not causing a panic immediately, this should make it *much* easier to get to the point.
- output the system's I/O ports

  ```
  cat /dev/port
  ```
- overwrite the memory device with zeroes

  ```
  cp /dev/zero /dev/mem
  ```
- flood system I/O ports with random numbers

  ```
  dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/port
  ```
- using SysRq, perform a system crash by a NULL pointer dereference:

  ```sh
  echo 1 >/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq # make sure SysRQ is fully enabled
  echo c >/proc/sysrq-trigger    # pull the trigger
  ```

I didn't try any of these. ([source 01](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/9-lethal-linux-commands-never-run/), [source 02](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt), [How to cause kernel panic with a single command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66197/how-to-cause-kernel-panic-with-a-single-command), [source 04](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysrq.txt))

Comment: @George  *I know* , but others who stumble upon this question don't know.

Comment: I had just tried overwriting `/dev/mem` with `dd`, and all it did was printing "Killed".

Comment: Actually I just tried all four of your suggestions in a VM and none of them had the slightest effect. It was a 16.04 live system, if that matters.

Comment: @dessert `panic_on_oops` will change the behavior in case a kernel bug occurs, it does not immediately crash your machine (see man [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Trying:

```
cd /proc
```

Followed by:

```
sudo kill *
```

Should do the trick