# What does :(){ :|:& };: do?

Tags: command-line, bash

What does this do: `:(){ :|:& };:`.

I was reading through encyclopedia dramatica and saw that command.

It just being above `rm -rf / --a-flag-we-don't-mention-here` makes me anxious about trying it out to see. Any insights on what it might be? I tried googling but the symbols make it impossible to search.

Comment: See [Why did the command “:(){ :|: & };:” make my system lag so badly I had to reboot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159491/why-did-the-command-make-my-system-lag-so-badly-i-had-to-reboot)

Comment: Sorry for the edit but its better to not openly mention that flag to protect people.

Comment: This is a fork bomb in Bash. See http://askubuntu.com/a/159494/15003 for what it actually means.

Comment: @Videonauth people are not to be put in sanboxes, it is not up to us to juge whether or not --a-flag-should-be-mentioned-here, so here is is for the curious: `--no-preserve-root`.
It disables the checks to prevent deletions from the root user, so use very carefully.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In fact what you posted there is called a fork bomb, because it does exactly that.  It is a Bash function which calls itself recursively. You can replace the `:` with a name if you want so it becomes more obvious:

```
fu {
    fu | fu &
}; fu
```

So `fu` calls itself, piping its output through itself again.  In this way it fills up your processor with requests.

It is not harmful, beside the fact that you may have to reboot your computer the hard way because it becomes unresponsive.

It is often used by sysadmin to test user process limitations on a server.